# How do I get a specific drive's icon for any version of Windows?

Tags: .net, windows, winforms, icons

In a .NET WinForms app, how do I get a specific drive's icon (C:\ for example) for whatever version of Windows the client might be running?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know if it will work, but you could try [this](http://www.codeguru.com/csharp/csharp/cs_misc/icons/article.php/c4261), pointing at the drive root.

Answer (score 0):

[SHGetFileInfo](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb762179(VS.85).aspx) is how the operating system exposes information about objects in the file system. How you go about calling it from a .NET WinForms app? I can't help you there.